# How to get the first date of the current month in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I'm trying to get the first and last date of the current month using Node.js.

Following code is working perfectly in browser (Chrome):

```
var date = new Date(), y = date.getFullYear(), m = date.getMonth();
var firstDay = new Date(y, m, 1);
var lastDay = new Date(y, m + 1, 0);

console.log(firstDay);
console.log(lastDay);
```

But it is showing a different result in Node.js. How can I fix it?

Comment: what are the different results? post results for browser/nodejs

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481963/how-come-my-javascript-node-js-is-giving-me-the-incorrect-timestamp) may help.

Comment: In browser
Tue Dec 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)Thu Dec 31 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)

In node js
2015-11-30T18:30:00.000Z - 2015-12-30T18:30:00.000Z

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing the native `Date` object in the accepted answer is bad practice; don't do that ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/8859896/3929494 )

You should use moment.js to give you a consistent environment for handling dates in JavaScript between node.js and *all* browsers - see it as an abstraction layer. http://momentjs.com/ - it's quite easy to use.

A very similar example is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26131085/3929494

You can try it on-line at https://tonicdev.com/jadaradix/momentjs

Comment: I don't think anybody *needs* to use moment.js to get consistency in Date output between two JS environments. You've not explained here why the OP has a difference in date output.

Comment: I've changed "need" to "should". Using methods like `endOf` will void a lot of boilerplate. Older browsers also make mistakes with dates which a library like moment.js will take care of. It's a clear win when you have to deal with internationalisation as well. I don't know why there is a difference; I think my point is that using moment.js would remove all possible differences.

Comment: I am not discrediting moment.js as a good abstraction, I'm just saying that moment.js itself is not an answer to the specific issue. It may help as a blanket problem-solver but it doesn't educate anybody on the differences between NodeJS and browser time keeping. I'll +1 as it's better than the current reigning answer.

Answer (score 0):

The browser output is showing the date in the current time zone, node.js is showing the date GMT / Zulu time zone.

(Edit: Code added). Something like this

```
var offset = (new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60) * -1;
var d = new Date();
var tmpDate = new Date(d.getTime()+offset);
var y = tmpDate.getFullYear();
var m = tmpDate.getMonth();
var firstDay = new Date(y, m, 1);
var lastDay = new Date(y, m + 1, 0);

console.log(tmpDate.toString());
console.log(firstDay.toString());
console.log(lastDay.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file **dates.js** and add the following code. To execute this code run the command **node dates.js** from your terminal. You can use this function to get first and last days dates in a given month. I tested this on **node 12**

```
const getDays = () => {
    const date = new Date();
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    let f = new Date(year, month, 1).getDate();
    let l = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();

    f = f < 10 ? '0'+f : f;
    l = l < 10 ? '0'+l : l;
    month = month < 10 ? '0'+month : month;
    const firstDay = new Date(`${year}-${month}-${f}`);
    const lastDay = new Date(`${year}-${month}-${l}`);

    console.log({
        "firstDay": firstDay,
        "lastDay": lastDay
    });

};

getDays();
```

Answer (score -2):

Look at the code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Please Rate if it helps</title>
    <script>
        Date.prototype.getMonthStartEnd = function (start) {
            var StartDate = new Date(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth(), 1);
            var EndDate = new Date(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth() + 1, 0);
            return [StartDate, EndDate];
        }
        window.onload = function () {
            document.write(new Date().getMonthStartEnd());
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How can i change its Format into DD/MM/YYYY ?

Comment: How is this answer supposed to help? It doesn't address the discrepancy between NodeJS and the browser that the OP claims to have seen...

Comment: I'm not a geek programmer in node or javascript, This code is giving me exactly what i want.

Comment: This is clearly not a NodeJS solution. It also modify Date object. But OP accepts :( because he is not a geek

Comment: @shennan can you post the correct answer or any workaround ?